# Command similar to pygame's get_rel() in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame, python-3.5

I was wondering if when I bind the `<Motion>` event to a function, if in that function I could define an `x` and `y` variable using a version of pygame's `mouse.get_rel()`, but in tkinter.

Comment: What does `event.get_rel()` do? I don't see it in the [documentation](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html).

Comment: You can get the x,y of the event. You can get the x.y of the widget relative to the window,and you can get the x,y of the window. From there it's just a tiny bit of math.

Comment: @martineau Pardon me, it's mouse.get_rel()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Event processing is different in `tkinter` than in `pygame`, so instead of direct `mouse.get_rel()` equivalent, it seemed more appropriate to create something that would call a callback function every time the mouse moved (which is what binding to the `'<Motion>'` event accomplishes). To assist in doing this a `RelativeMotion` class is defined to hide and encapsulate as many of the messy details as possible. Far below is a screenshot of it running.

```
import tkinter as tk

class RelativeMotion(object):
    """ Relative mouse motion controller. """
    def __init__(self, callback):
        self.__call__ = self._init_location  # first call
        self.callback = callback

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Implicit invocations of special methods resolve to instance's type.
        self.__call__(*args, **kwargs)  # redirect call to instance itself

    def _init_location(self, event):
        self.x, self.y = event.x, event.y  # initialize current position
        self.__call__ = self._update_location  # change for any subsequent calls

    def _update_location(self, event):
        dx, dy = event.x-self.x, event.y-self.y
        self.x, self.y = event.x, event.y
        self.callback(dx, dy)

class Application(tk.Frame):  # usage demo
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.createWidgets()
        self.relative_motion = RelativeMotion(self.canvas_mouse_motion)
        self.canvas.bind('<Motion>', self.relative_motion)  # when over canvas

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.motion_str = tk.StringVar()
        self.canvas_mouse_motion(0, 0)  # initialize motion_str text
        label_width = len(self.motion_str.get())
        self.motion_lbl = tk.Label(self, bg='white', width=label_width,
                                   textvariable=self.motion_str)
        self.motion_lbl.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.quit_btn = tk.Button(self, text='Quit', command=self.quit)
        self.quit_btn.grid(row=1, column=0)

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width='2i', height='2i', bg='white')
        self.canvas.grid(row=1, column=1)

    def canvas_mouse_motion(self, dx, dy):
        self.motion_str.set('{:3d}, {:3d}'.format(dx, dy))

app = Application()
app.master.title('Relative Motion Demo')
app.mainloop()
```

**Running**

[image: relative motion demo screenshot]